# How to plot a 3D function and an arrow pointing in the direction of the gradient vector?

Tags: plotting, graphics, vector

I need to plot a 3D function and show an arrow pointing from the curve into the direction of the gradient vector. I also need to plot a ContourPlot of the level surfaces of the function, also with an arrow pointing from a point in the direction of the gradient vector, except using an angle theta that I need to manipulate. What I have right now is:

```
In[2]:= f[x_, y_] = 9 - x^2 - y^2;

In[3]:= fx[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], x]

Out[3]= -2 x

In[4]:= fy[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], y]

Out[4]= -2 y

In[11]:= unitgradient[x_, y_] = {fx[x, y]/(Sqrt[4 x^2 + 4 y^2]), 
  fy[x, y]/(Sqrt[4 x^2 + 4 y^2])}

Out[11]= {-((2 x)/Sqrt[4 x^2 + 4 y^2]), -((2 y)/Sqrt[4 x^2 + 4 y^2])}

In[7]:= mag[x_, y_] = Sqrt[4 x^2 + 4 y^2]

Out[7]= Sqrt[4 x^2 + 4 y^2]

In[35]:= Manipulate[
 GraphicsGrid[
  {
   {
    Show[
     ContourPlot3D[z == f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, 0, 10}, 
      PlotRange -> 15, ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0.4], Purple}, 
      Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
      AxesLabel -> Automatic],
     (*Graphics3D[{Red,PointSize\[Rule]0.02,Point[{a,b,f[a,b]}]}],
     Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.4],InfinitePlane[{{a,b,0},{a,b,f[a,
     b]},{a+1,b,0}}]}],
     ParametricPlot3D[{t,b,f[t,b]},{t,-4,4},
     PlotStyle\[Rule]{Thickness[0.01],Yellow}],
     ParametricPlot3D[{1,0,fx[a,b]}*t+{a,b,f[a,b]},{t,-3,3},
     PlotStyle\[Rule]{Thickness[0.01],Blue}],
     ParametricPlot3D[{0,1,fy[a,b]}*t+{a,b,f[a,b]},{t,-3,3},
     PlotStyle\[Rule]{Thickness[0.01],Green}],
     ContourPlot3D[normal[a,b].{x-a,y-b,z-f[a,b]}\[Equal]0,{x,a-1,
     a+1},{y,b-1,b+1},{z,f[a,b]-2,f[a,b]+2},ContourStyle\[Rule]Orange],
     Graphics3D[{Cyan,PointSize\[Rule]0.02,Point[{a+dx,b,f[a,b]+fx[a,
     b]*dx}]}],
     Graphics3D[{Pink,PointSize\[Rule]0.02,Point[{a,b+dy,f[a,b]+fy[a,
     b]*dy}]}],*)

     Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{a, b, f[a, b]}]}],
     Graphics3D[{Green, Arrowheads[0.03], Thickness[0.009], 
       Arrow[{{a, b, f[a, b]}, {a + fx[a, b]/mag[a, b], 
          b + fy[a, b]/mag[a, b], f[a, b] + mag[a, b]}}]}]
     ],
    Show[ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
      ContourLabels -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}], 
     Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{a, b}]}], 
     Graphics[{Green, Arrowheads[0.03], Thickness[0.006], 
       Arrow[{{a, b}, {a + Cos[\[Theta]], b + Sin[\[Theta]]}}]}], 
     ImageSize -> Medium
     ]
    }
   }
  ],
 {a, -3, 3},
 {b, -3, 3},
 (*{dx,-0.5,0.5},
 {dy,-0.5,0.5},*)
 {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}
 ]
```

But I'm getting a ton of errors and I honestly don't know where to go.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is `f`? What is `mag`? What errors are you getting?

Comment: sorry, ive edited it to have the full code now.

Comment: never mind, i just figured it out. thanks for replying anyways.

Comment: Great. Could you please add a comment explaining what was wrong so others with a similar problem can benefit from your solution.